# htaccess rewrite - rewrite http folder to https folder

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Just like in title. 
I would like to redirect whole folder (in this example it will be /w1/) from http to https.
How to redirect this: http://testdomain.com/system**/w1/**(and all with that folder) to this: https://testdomain.com/system**/w1/**(and all with that folder). So for example http://testdomain.com/system/w1/w1_input.php will be redirected to **https**://testdomain.com/system/w1/w1_input.php

I was tring to use that kind of rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/w1(.*)$ https://testdomain.com/system/w1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this did nothing

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a .htaccess and/or rewrite. Simply put a RedirectMatch into your non-ssl host definition at the http.conf level.

```
<Host example.com:80>
   RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://example.com$1
</Host>
```

Comment: This redirects everything, OP only wants to redirect the `/w1/` folder.

Comment: That can easily be added to the match.

Comment: I do not have an access to that file - i can only use htaccess

Answer (score 1):

If these rules are in an htaccess file the leading slash is stripped off the URI before being put through the rewrite engine, so the `^/w1` won't match anything. It looks like you may have these rules in an htaccess file in the `/system/` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^w1/(.*)$ https://testdomain.com/system/w1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or if not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^system/w1/(.*)$ https://testdomain.com/system/w1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Those rules are not working. It does not redirect to https

Comment: your htaccess is where ? what url did you try and it didn't work ?